# Hide a form field based on selection on previous tab of a form

Tags: jquery, dynamics-365

I have a form with multiple tabs which are accessed using a next button. The jQuery code I have created works if the field is on the same tab but it is not working when its assigned to a field on a different tab. The question is "if question 11 (current tab) dropdown select is no then hide question 19 (next page)".

```
//if Q11 = No hide Q19
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ahitask_brop04seccq11").change(SetFieldsVisibilityQ11b);
  $("#ahitask_brop04seccq11").change();
});

function SetFieldsVisibilityQ11b() {
  var selectedValue = $("#ahitask_brop04seccq11").val();

  if (selectedValue == "352230001")
  {
    $("#ahitask_brop05secdq19_label").closest("tr").hide();
    $("#ahitask_brop05secdq19").prop("required",false).closest("tr").hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#ahitask_brop05secdq19_label").closest("tr").show();
    $("#ahitask_brop05secdq19").prop("required",true).closest("tr").show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61748779/edit) then click `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: How are your "tabs" generated?  Are they all loaded up-front and just .show()/.hide() as you go between them?  or do you make an ajax call each time the tab changes?  You also use the terms `tab` and then `next page` - so is it a tab or is there a page change? Or do you mean browser "tab" (which would not be "a form with multiple tabs"? These are all very different things.

Comment: @freedomn-m, to clarify, firstly I am working with a Dynamics 365 entity form set up with different tabs and one web page. The steps (next or previous) on the form are generate by the tabs on the entity form. The jQuery .show()/.hide() is applied as you go through each of the tabs. When I click next and move to the next tab the on change jquery (code above) does not appear to be applying to the next tab.

Comment: First step, in your `SetFieldsVisibilityQ11b` add `console.log($("#ahitask_brop05secdq19_label").length)` is that value 0?  2nd step add a console.log for `selectedValue` (or use debugger instead of console.log)